# Ancestry: skip element from scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ancestry

Using gem ancestry.

How skip self element from Category::ActiveRecordRelation or need use scope?

```
= simple_form_for @category do |f|
  = f.input :parent_id, collection: Category.roots
```

Something like:

```
= f.input :parent_id, collection: Category.roots.except(@category)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
= f.input :parent_id, collection: Category.roots.where("id <> ?", @category.id)
```

**or via a scope**

category.rb

```
scope :except, lambda{ |category| where("id <> ?", category.id) }
```

then

```
= f.input :parent_id, collection: Category.roots.except(@category)
```

Comment: I'm use this, but I think what this are realized from gem ancestry.